# Op-amp resistors

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, resistors

So I am using a LF351 op-amp to amplify a 0.5Vpp 50kHz signal to a 25Vpp 50kHz. So its a closed loop inverting amplifier with a feedback resistor and a resistor at Vin. What should my resistor values be. I know my gain is 50 and the ratio of my feedback resitor to the other resistor is 50:1. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is this a duplicate? Why does not your previous question how to choose resistors for op-amps did not answer this? You have also not accepted any answers for your questions.

Comment: With a supply voltage max of +/-18V, you can't get the output range you want

Comment: Yea still do not really understand and I have accepted previous answers

Comment: What do you mean @Scott Seidman

Comment: @ScottSeidman, 25 is less than 36. The datasheet gives a swing of 13.5 V (typ) with +/- 15 V supplies and 10 kohm load. I believe a "+/-" is implied. Also see Fig 4 in the ST datasheet. 25 V pp output is explicitly shown.

Comment: You ought to edit your question to state that you need to know how high the values can be or you're just going over the same ground. Your previous question (and my answer) established the low value for the feedback resistor and now, all you need to cover are the limitations that affect the choice at the other end of the scale i.e. why isn't 100 MΩ a good choice for the feedback resistor. You also need to state what load resistor you are using.

Comment: My load resistor as mentioned, is 2kohms and I really do not know how to go about covering the limitations etc.

Comment: @Fiidisks there is no single answer. Any resistances with ratios 1:50 can be used. But If I say put a 1kohm and a 50kohm resistor there, then you come and complain that that's no good because the 1kohm loads too much your source or something else. You can also try out different values in a simulator to find out the best range for whatever conditions you need to fulfill, other than having 50x gain. Also, the LF351 cannot output a 25Vpp signal into 2kohm load, not at +/- 15V supplies, it can with +/- 18V supplies.

Comment: You need to say where the input is coming from, more than where the output is going

Comment: @Justme What are the pro and cons of higher/lower resistor values?

Comment: @Fiidisks I am quite sure I already mentioned in my answer to your previous question about those. Too low, does not work. Too high, does not work.

Comment: I don't think you mentioned the pros and cons though. All you said is it can't be too high or too low

Comment: @Fiidisks I did. When resistances go near the too low end, it starts loading down the source voltage and it requires more current drive from the op-amp. There is no limit where it does not load at all and where it loads too much. So it needs to be high enough and it depends on your source. If it is near the too high end, the feedback starts to have problems with driving the feedback fast enough. So it must be low enough. Again, there is no set limit when it is perfect and where it is too high, you set the limit how much distortion is acceptable, and make it low enough to fit that limit.

Comment: @Fiidisks does this happen to be a school assignment? Someone else just put exactly the same question with almost same wording here.

Answer (score 2):

> LF351 op-amp to amplify a 0.5Vpp 50kHz signal to a 25Vpp 50kHz.

This can be done over a wide range of 50R, R values.

For minimum values, current limiting and max swing reduction begin to have effect at 10k for the load on CMOS and in this case, with a bipolar output, they show specs for 10k and 3k to show some reduction differences.  Power consumption for a 10k 25Vpp square wave is 63 mW which defines that a good minimum 50R load here resulting in an exact R-value of 200 Ohms.

For maximum values, 1M to 33M is often used for a max value depending on the dust environment expected as humidity can cause surface leakage near these values over time with forced air possibly accelerating the accumulation.

If 50R= 1M then R=20k.

You might be concerned about input offset voltage and mismatched Req values inducing extra offset so you would need 20k on both inputs. But this FET input device has exceptional low input bias 200 pA max and 20 nA over temp, so you can Choose Vin+ load R to be any value in the range of 50 Ohm ~ 33M for reasons of defining your input impedance.
Now you just have to choose any pair of values in this range.

There are many exceptions to choose values outside this range and outside the scope of this question.